# Scrolling SKReferenceNodes from sks files

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to scroll `SKReferenceNodes` created with my sks files I put together in the interface builder. I have scrolled `SKSpriteNodes` before, and I am trying to use the same code, but my `SKReferenceNodes` seem to have no frame, and so I can't position them.

Here is my `SKReferenceNode` setup:

```
let BG_POINTS_PER_SEC = 50
var dt:NSTimeInterval = 0
let background1 = SKReferenceNode(fileNamed:"BackgroundScene1")
let background2 = SKReferenceNode(fileNamed:"BackgroundScene2")
```

in didMoveToView

```
background1.position = CGPointZero;
background2.position = CGPointMake(background1.frame.size.width, 0)

self.addChild(background1)
self.addChild(background2)
```

in update

```
moveBackground()

func moveBackground() {
  let bgVelocity = CGPoint(x:-BG_POINTS_PER_SEC, y:0)
  let amtToMove = bgVelocity *CGFloat(dt)
  background1.position = background1.position + amtToMove
  background2.position = background2.position + amtToMove
  if (background1.position.x <= background1.frame.size.width) {
   background1.position.x = CGPointMake(background2.position.x + background2.frame.size.width, background1.position.y)
  }
  if (background2.position.x <= background2.frame.size.width) {
   background2.position.x = CGPointMake(background1.position.x + background1.frame.size.width, background2.position.y)
  }
}
```

Again this works for the scrolling background using a `SKSpriteNode`, but the `SKReferenceNode` returns a 0 frame. Is this even possible to scroll `SKReferenceNodes` from sks files like this?